# OpenLayers custom units measure

Tags: prototype, openlayers

I'm trying to add a custom measurement unit in OpenLayers 2.12. All that is available by default in OpenLayers is:

```
displaySystemUnits: {
  geographic: ['dd'],
  english: ['mi', 'ft', 'in'],
  metric: ['km', 'm'],
}
```

I would like to be able to extend this and add a custom one to measure in miles only. For example, if measurement is less than 1 mile, say half a mile, display it as 0.5.

I don't want to go as far as editing the actual OpenLayers Measurement.js by adding the following as it is not scalable for future upgrades:

```
myCustomUnits: ['mi', 'mi']
```

Any ideas how I can extend OpenLayers to do the above?

Thanks
Dimitrios

Answer (score 2):

Have actually found the way to overwrite the displaySystemUnits by using the following code:

```
OpenLayers.Control.Measure.prototype.displaySystemUnits = {
 geographic: ['dd'],
 english: ['mi', 'ft', 'in'],
 metric: ['km', 'm'],
 myCustomUnits: ['mi', 'mi']
};
```